# TypeScript type float from 0 to 1

Tags: typescript, types

With Typescript, is it possible to define a type of a float (number) that's between 0 and 1 inclusively?

If this isn't possible at all, a way to define the type of an integer between 0 and 100 inclusively.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a type declaration but is there a problem with checking `if(num >= 0 || num <= 100)`? Do you have a specific use case for such a type?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't discriminate types of floating point numbers. Branded types (types which can only exist by assertion) are the conventional approach. If you can show how you intend to use such a type, a more suitable answer can be provided.

Comment: I agree, use cases are needed.  You can write `type XXX = 0|1|2|`...snip...`|100` and even get the compiler to compute it for you, but it might not be worth the hassle to use.   Given `let x: XXX = 99`, the compiler does not know that `x=x+1` is safe, nor does it realize that a subsequent `x++` is *unsafe*.  If your use case has to do with performing mathematical operations, I'd just give up and use runtime checks alone, probably.

Answer (score 3):

Defining the type of an integer between 0 and 100 is trivial, albeit tedious

```js
type IntBetween0And100 = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ...
```

The same thing for floats, not so easy.

I would approach the problem by making use of [smart constructors](https://dev.to/gcanti/functional-design-smart-constructors-14nb). The idea is quite simple, you shift the responsibility of ensuring that a value is of the correct type from the type system (which is unable to do it) to the runtime.

A simplified example might look like this.

```js
type Option<T> = null | T // a simplified Option monad
type FloatBetween0And100 = number

const isFloatBetween0And100 = (n: unknown): n is FloatBetween0And100 => typeof n === 'number' && n <= 100 && n >= 0

const makeFloatBetween0And100 = (n: number): Option<FloatBetween0And100> => isFloatBetween0And100(n) ? n : null
```

The article I linked above goes a lot more in detail about this approach, check it out.